# rxjs "find" with observable of hashmap of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, hashmap

Say I have class `hiObject` where it has variables `id: number` and a `value: number` inside. \

Then I have `hiObjects$: Observable<HashMap<hiObject>>  = ...` in　an other class.

I wish to find the `hiObject` inside this hashmap observable where `id = 2`, and assign their `value` to an `digit$: Observable<number>`

Currently I'm using `this.digit$ = hiObjects$.pipe(map(hiObjects) => for(const index in hiObjects)...)`, basically looping through the entire hashmap and looking for when `id` is equal to 2.

But I think there should be another alternate where you use rxjs `find` and `map`, wondering if anyone could help. Thank you!

***EDIT***: Think hashmap does not allow find, so this question is useless now..

TS:

```
export interface hiObject {
  id?: number;
  value?: number;
}

export class smth implements OnInit{
  public digit$: Observable<number>;
  public hiObjects$: Observable<HashMap<hiObject>> = ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.digit$ = this.hiObjects$.pipe(
      map((collections) => {
        for (const index in collections) ...})
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For me it's not super clear. Please upload your specific implementation to stackblitz so we will have easier time to understand your needs.

Comment: @monogate I have inserted some code blocks, if it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

You're close, use `.find` and then the `.value` if it's actually found

```
this.digit$ = hiObjects$.pipe(
    // this finds the hiObject that has an id of 2, and then returns the value
    map(hiObjects => hiObjects.find(id => id === 2)?.value)
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it's giving me either `Type 'hiObject' has no call signatures`, or `hiObjects.find is not a function`  ` when I have `map(hiObjects : any) =>...`

Comment: Do you have an example of what hiObject looks like?

Comment: It's an interface which looks something similar to what I have in the question code block